# ¿Cómo mostrar un fragment dando click a un item del RecyclerView en el Adaptador?

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview, onclick

Solicito su ayuda, tengo un **RecyclerView** normal utilizando **cadrView**, lo que estoy intentando hacer es abrir un fragment diferente desde cada item del dicho **RecyclerView**, pero al parecer me da error, no me reconoce el **getFragmentManager**

**Este es mi Adaptador - codigo segmentado**

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderPerrito holder, final int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(lista_cat_dog.get(position).getNombre_producto());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(lista_cat_dog.get(position).getImagen_producto());
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pos_marcada = position;

                switch (pos_marcada){
                    case 0:
                        Fragment fragmento = new arroz_pollo();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragmento);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista_cat_dog.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolderPerrito extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        CardView cardView;
        public ViewHolderPerrito(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_cat_dog);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_prod);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CardViewIDPerro);
        }
    }
```

[image: Imagen]

Comment: Puedes mostrar el recicler view completo al igual que la actividad o el fragmento desde donde lo llamas?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta pasandole la actividad en la que se encuentra.

Para esto deberás solicitar al iniciar tu adaptador el `Activity`. Esto se lo puedes asignar de la siguiente manenra: ej: `YourNameActivity.this`.

Posteriormente asigna esto a una variable Activity activity.

Y realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```